# Why does the empty set have a cardinality of zero?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the following sets:

$$ A = \{1, 2, \{1,2\}, \emptyset \} $$

$$ B = \emptyset $$

My book says that $|A| = 4$ and $|B| = 0$. Why is $\emptyset$ considered an element if it's a subset, but not when it's on its own?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I made a small mistake, I edited it to display what I actually meant.

Comment: How many elements does $\{\{1,2\}\}$ contain? Hint: Not two.

Comment: Now tell,what is the power set of an empty set?

Comment: "Why is $\emptyset$ considered an element if it's a subset, but not when it's on its own?" shows you haven't understood the notation (nor the terminology). In the first line the symbol $\emptyset$ designates an element (not a subset) of $A$. In the second line it designates the _value_ of $B$. If it were $B=\{\emptyset\}$ instead it would be an element of $B$, and one would have $|B|=1$.

Comment: So $∅  ≡ \{\}\space ∴\space A=\{1,2,\{1,2\},\{\}\}$ ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The "philosophical" issue behind this which in the beginning confuses many people is that in everyday mathematics you're almost always dealing with "typed" sets - meaning that the elements of the sets you'll encounter are always of the same kind: You might have sets of natural numbers like $\{1,2,3\}$ or sets of reals like the interval $[0,\pi)$.  Later you'll maybe encounter sets of vectors or sets of functions and so on.  Still, the "roles" are always kind of clear, sets are "containers" for "other" objects - the ones you are "really" dealing with.  [Things get muddy once you start with topology, though.]

But in (axiomatic) set theory there are no "other" objects.  Everything you'll ever encounter are sets - which entails that all sets have to be able to play both roles, the "container role" as well as the "element role".

So, your $A$ above is a set which is a container for four other things - and these four other things are also sets and one of them is $\emptyset$.  (In other words, $\emptyset$ here plays the "role" of an *element* of a set.)  But for the cardinality of $A$ the only thing that "counts" is *how many* objects it contains, so it is $4$.  It doesn't matter whether one of its elements - $\emptyset$ - has cardinality $0$ or whether another element - $\{1,2\}$ - has cardinality $2$.  Each element of a set has the same "right" to be counted - no matter whether it's the tiny empty set or a huge uncountable bouncer like $\mathbb R$.

But $\emptyset$ can also be viewed in its "role" as a *set* containing objects.  And as a set it is a container for zero elements (by definition).  So its cardinality is $0$.

[In case you're wondering: Yes, $1$ and $2$ are also sets as far as set theory is concerned.  More about this can e.g. be found in other answers on this site, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922797/what-is-the-meaning-of-set-theoretic-notation-0-and-1/922986).]

Comment: The untyped nature of the universe isn't the heart of the questioner's problem I think and in any case it is possible to have axiomatic set theories with urelements.

Answer (score 8):

Sets can be elements of other sets. They can also be subsets. That is irrelevant for defining cardinality of a set.

The cardinality of a set is "the number of elements in a set". $\varnothing$ has no elements. It has zero elements. So its cardinality $0$. Much like that $\{1,2\}$ has cardinality $2$, regardless to the fact it is an element of $A$.

Comment: Ah, so it has no elements but can still be an element?

Comment: Yes. $\varnothing$ is an element of *every* power set.

Comment: @Phaptitude: To have or to be. The empty set never _has_ any element, but it can _be_ one.

Comment: @Phaptitude: I have no husband, but I still can be a husband. On the other hand, my car has wheels but isn't a wheel. It sounds that you are at a stage where you are looking at combinations of words without understanding their meaning.